# no such file or directory error(python)

Tags: file, python-3.x, nltk, text-mining, path-finding

i have file with 3989 .txt file.i used nltk to read the id of the txt files and put all the ids in files, now i want to read each txt file and have two outputs,one corpus with the text of all txt file and secondly and array with each txt file as rows.but i cannot even read files, i have this error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`. how can i fix it and have my two outputs?any help is appreciated!!
here is my code:

```
from nltk.corpus import BracketParseCorpusReader

corpus_root = '/Users/sima/Downloads/Selected 20-newsgroupto work on/kole databaseha'
wordlists = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '.*') 
files = wordlists.fileids()

for file in files:
    f = open(file,'r')
    lines = f.read()
    print(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to *[join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)* the *basename* to the *root* directory unless your cwd is where the files are located which by your error they are not:

```
from nltk.corpus import BracketParseCorpusReader
from os.path import join

corpus_root = '/Users/sima/Downloads/Selected 20-newsgroupto work on/kole databaseha'
wordlists = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '.*')
files = wordlists.fileids()

for file in files:
    with  open(join(corpus_root, file)) as f:
        lines = f.read()
        print(lines)
```

Comment: i run the code, this time different error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/Users/sima/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf7 in position 557: invalid start byte

Comment: That has nothing to do with your original error, that is because of an encoding issue, try setting `encoding="latin-1"` in the open call

Comment: i changed it to :with open(join(corpus_root, file), encoding = 'latin-1') as f: and it works.thanks,